# Advanced Custom Fields on Product Categories in Wordpress disappear when Category has Products applied to it

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, advanced-custom-fields

I can successfully get my Advanced Custom Fields to display on Category pages that don’t have Products applied to them. But as soon as I apply products to the category, then the Custom Fields stop displaying on the frontend.
Any ideas how I can retain the Custom Fields display and also show product listings on the Category pages?
Example page:
[Category example URL](https://tempwebdev.com/?product_cat=hayley-gillespie)

Example code that works when no products are applied:

```
<?php the_field(‘categtest1’); ?>
<?php the_field(‘richt’); ?>
```

Comment: _Where_ are the above lines placed - are they somewhere inside the loop? Then the global post ID will be that of an individual product at this time, so these functions will be looking for the field under the wrong object. You will need to pass in the post ID of the category as second parameter then. `get_queried_object_id` should be able to help getting that.

Comment: And the category ID might have to be prefixed with `category_`, according to https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

Comment: @CBroe I tried including the code you suggested, but I had no luck. I'm a bit unsure of myself here. I've included a link to the contents of the archive-product.php file that sits in my child theme's themes/woocommerce directory.
https://tempwebdev.com/wp-content/themes/storefront-child/woocommerce/tempsample.txt
Possibly you could guide me from here?